# Conditionals/syntax confusion

Tags: javascript

I have a question understanding some JavaScript syntax, below:

```
var myObject = {
    value: 0;
    increment: function (inc) {
        this.value += typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
    }
};
myObject.increment(  );
document.writeln(myObject.value);    // 1
myObject.increment(2);
document.writeln(myObject.value);    // 3
```

Specifically:

```
this.value += typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
```

Is this line saying that if:

```
typeof inc === 'number'
```

then:

```
this.value += inc
```

Any good way to think about this or resource to help understand would be appreciated.

Comment: This is saying that if "inc" is a valid number then use it to increment, otherwise use 1. You could also write: this.value += (isNaN(inc) ? 1 : inc);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, it's called a ternary operator. If the statement resolves to true it does the first option if not it resolves the second. It can be broken down into a simple if/else

```
if (typeof inc === 'number') this.value += inc;
else this.value++;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed saying that if `typeof inc === 'number'` then to add `inc` to `this.value`, and otherwise to add 1 to `this.value`.  The pattern is an example of the ternary operator, which returns the left side of the `:` if the condition is true, and the right side of the `:` if false.

Ternary operations are somewhat more commonly used for assignment like:

```
// Assign the greater of y and z to x (or z if they're equal)
var x = y > z ? y : z;

// equivalent to:
if (y > z) {
  var x = y;
}
else var x = z;
```

In this case though, it is used to return a number to the `+=` operator.

Comment: Thanks @michael, for your explanation and the sample code you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

It's the [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator.

```
this.value += typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
```

is the same as

```
if (typeof inc === 'number') {
    this.value += inc;
} else {
    this.value += 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a speed benefit to either variant? I'd guess not, and if that is the case, as someone just getting into javascript i would consider adopting the latter as a style.

Comment: No speed benefit, I would use that latter as well. It's just more readable.

Comment: It's the conditional operator, which is an example of a ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator is just a shorthand version of if/else. It's sometimes helpful to put the conditional expression inside parentheses to better see the condition being tested:

```
this.value = (typeof inc === 'number') ? inc : 1;
```

So if typeof inc results in "number" then assign inc to this.value, otherwise assign 1.